# How do I ask Robospice when pending requests are completed?

Tags: android, network-programming, android-activity, robospice

I'm using Robospice. I want to write some reusable code to stop ProgressBars and ProgressDialogs as soon as pending network requests have cleared for the current activity. However, I'm running into a couple of problems.

I'm watching when requests have completed by instrumenting a custom SpiceServiceListener to call my custom callbacks implemented within each activity. During onRequestAdded(), I show any Progress UI element. During onRequestSucceeded(), onRequestFailed(), and onRequestCancelled(), I check getSpiceManager().getPendingRequestCount() to see if it reaches zero and then hide any Progress UI elements.

The pending request count never reaches zero in my app (at least inside these three methods), but it seems to stop at one. This is true even though I can see from the Retrofit logging that my requests all appear to be completed.

Is the pending request count global or is it specific to the current Activity and its spice manager instance? Is there a better method to watch for all requests finishing within the current activity?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have an answer. I missed instrumenting onRequestProcessed(), so the number of pending network requests never appeared to reach zero. The pending request count now does reach zero.

I still don't know if the count is global or local to the current activity and its SpiceManager instance, but I'm getting useful results from my new code.

Comment: It's local to the instance of the SpiceManager.

Comment: Thanks, this is useful. This means that I can check pending requests only for the current activity and its immediate context.

Comment: Quick followup... I can see the SpiceManager is storing the request data as a Collections.SynchronizedMap and it's performing a size() call to get the pending request count. However, I can clearly see that the current request is counted as pending. Two request callbacks may call getPendingRequestCount() while both requests are being processed even if the calling function is synchronized. As a result, I see both functions may come back with two pending requests due to race conditions. Is there any way to definitively know that the SpiceManager is done without race conditions?

Comment: How does one instrument onRequestProcessed?

Comment: Create your own custom SpiceServiceListener and set it using getSpiceManager().addSpiceServiceListener(thisVarImplementsSpiceServiceListener);